# Android: how to create that fancy quicklaunch buttons as a widget?

Tags: android, widget

Android Nougat has Shortcuts feature. However, older versions can use widgets to create "buttons" that looks like another app. For e.g.

[image]

Google Play Music can add widget that looks like a button and on tap it will open playlist directly.

How to create such things step-by-step (including key moments).

Thank you!

Comment: Just create a fancy a layout for your widget and make it start you application once it is clicked. However, support for widget layout is very limited. In order to do it step by step you need to comprehend several tasks that do not belong to the scope of a single question on stackoverflow. First search how to create widgets and then how to assemble the layout you desire

Comment: @humble well, I've done this, but my round button always squashed to fill the whole widget. Even tho I've set adjustviewbounds and scaletype correctly.

Comment: Perhaps you could update your question emphasizing that your problem is configuring the layout